# Real Time Performance With Core Image Blend Modes

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm trying to do a really basic demo app that allows the user to pick an image and a blend mode and then drag and manipulate the blended image overtop of the background image. When the user is dragging the image overtop of the background I want real time performance (20+ fps on iPhone 4). The images are the same resolution as the screen.

Is this possible to do with core image? I have tried a couple different approaches but I can't seem to get the performance I want.

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
CIFilter * overlayBlendMode = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIOverlayBlendMode"];
[overlayBlendMode setValue:self.foregroundImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[overlayBlendMode setValue:self.backgroundImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

CIImage * test = [overlayBlendMode outputImage];

// render background image
[self.ciContext drawImage:test inRect:test.extent fromRect:test.extent];
```

This code is being executed each time display gets called from my GLKViewController.

And my setup code is:

```
self.glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
self.ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.glContext];

...

UIImage * foregroundImage = [ViewController imageScaledFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Smiley"] inRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
GLKTextureInfo * foregroundTexture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:foregroundImage.CGImage options:@{GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft: @(YES)} error:nil];
self.foregroundImage = [CIImage imageWithTexture:foregroundTexture.name size:foregroundImage.size flipped:NO colorSpace:nil];

UIImage *backgroundImage = [ViewController imageCenterScaledFromImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Kate.jpg"] inRect:(CGRect){0,0,self.renderBufferSize}];
GLKTextureInfo * backgroundTexture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:backgroundImage.CGImage options:@{GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft: @(YES)} error:nil];
self.backgroundImage = [CIImage imageWithTexture:backgroundTexture.name size:backgroundImage.size flipped:NO colorSpace:nil];
```

The performance I am getting is not what I expected, I was expecting 60fps since it is such a simple scene but on my iPad 4 I'm getting ~35 or so and I'm sure it would be worse on the iPhone 4 which is my lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set GLKViewController -> preferredFramesPerSecond to something other than its default 30?

Comment: Is the GLKView associated with the GLKViewController also set up with the EAGLContext that you initialize in your setup code? (Normally you can make the CIContext from the GLKView -> context parameter.)

Comment: Yup it is, I just did some more testing and on iPhone 4 I am getting < 5 fps. My guess right now is that core image is somehow adding a ton of overhead. I know if I dropped down to using OpenGL directly I would be getting real time performance easily.

Comment: Wow, less than 5 fps means there is something else going on. Even CoreImage can't be that bad. Is the test running in portrait mode or landscape mode? Using OpenGL in a rotated view is definitely a seriously slowing factor (also mentioned in the docs).

Comment: My view hierarchy looks like this: UIScrollView -> UIImageVIew -> UIView -> GLView  And this is in portrait. my view hierarchy is fairly complicated. I might try making a demo app and see if that is the problem.